# LogicException: Unable to read key from file file://C:\Users\vivek\pregent-app\app\Providers/../secrets/oauth\oauth-private.key

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to create api token for my apis when my API are run in postman I get this error

`LogicException: Unable to read key from file file://C:\Users\vivek\pregent-app\app\Providers/../secrets/oauth\oauth-private.key in file C:\Users\vivek\pregent-app\vendor\league\oauth2-ser`

I did some goggling and fount that I need to do

`php artisan passport:keys`

but when I do I am getting the following error

`file_put_contents(C:\Users\vivek\pregent-app\app\Providers/../secrets/oauth\oauth-public.key): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

inorder to clear this error I tried `php artisan config:cache` still I am getting same error how can I solve this

**note I am using larvel 9**

this is the error I am getting

```
 file_put_contents(C:\Users\vivek\pregent-app\app\Providers/../secrets/oauth\oauth-public.key): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory      

  at C:\Users\vivek\pregent-app\vendor\laravel\passport\src\Console\KeysCommand.php:54
     50▕                 file_put_contents($privateKey, Arr::get($keys, 'privatekey'));
     51▕             } else {
     52▕                 $key = RSA::createKey($this->input ? (int) $this->option('length') : 4096);
     53▕
  ➜  54▕                 file_put_contents($publicKey, (string) $key->getPublicKey());
     55▕                 file_put_contents($privateKey, (string) $key);
     56▕             }
     57▕
     58▕             $this->info('Encryption keys generated successfully.');

  1   C:\Users\vivek\pregent-app\vendor\laravel\passport\src\Console\KeysCommand.php:54
      file_put_contents()

  2   C:\Users\vivek\pregent-app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
      Laravel\Passport\Console\KeysCommand::handle()
```

Comment: Have you tried these commands: `php artisan optimize:clear` then `php artisan passport:install --force`

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42795011/oauth-private-key-does-not-exist-or-is-not-readable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [oauth-private.key does not exist or is not readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42795011/oauth-private-key-does-not-exist-or-is-not-readable)

Comment: attulay in my composer file i have  "laravel/passport": "^11.3",

Comment: @SemihSAHIN should i try it again

Comment: @SemihSAHIN php artisan passport:install --force is also giving same error

Comment: Did you try: `php artisan passport:keys`

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi i have tryed it still getting error pls check my question I have updated the full error I get

Comment: Check your 'secrets' directory, to see what's in there

Answer (score -3):

you can try these commands

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

once your cache is clear then you can do this commands

```
php artisan
```

Comment: stilll getting that errror

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).